# What all reasons the redis AOF file can corrupt?

Tags: linux, redis

I am running `redis` pod on `k3s` environment with path to `AOF` is mounted to a host path.
But I am seeing the pod going in to crash loop due to `bad AOF format`.
I can add some recovery strategies such as remove the `AOF` file and start with `RDB` (both `RDB` and `AOF` persistence is enabled, still there might some data loss with `RDB` as well) or indicate the error and start the `redis` fresh with out any data.

But I would like to avoid this `AOF` file corruption in the first place. But from `redis` documentation I could not get on what all reasons the file can corrupt.

Can someone please explain how the file get corrupted, if this corruption can be avoided or I should work only with the recovery strategies?

Comment: We have faced this issue also recently on a relative instable Kubernetes environment. Answer to this would be helpful. Methods of automated resolution would also be helpful as failures can occur at any time.